# How do I create conditions for both the original table and a left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

My database has 4 relevant tables for this query: clients, appointments, invoices, and invoice details.  I am trying to calculate the average amount a customer paid in the past year minus any tips.

*TABLES INVOLVED IN QUERY*

**Clients** = All basic client information.  I need this table so that I can limit it to what school the customer attends, and get their name and clientId

**Appointments** = This is all appointment information, which matches the client table based on clientId.  I need this table so that I can limit it to customers from this past year and get the appointment location.

**Invoices** = This would be the total costs of the invoice and relevant information about when we posted the invoice online.  This matches with my client table based on clientId.  I need this table so that I can sum all invoices posted to the account in the past year

**Invoice Detail** = This is for the contents of the invoice, each entry is an item purchased with a price.  This matches with my invoices table based on invoiceId.  I need to include this table so I can remove tips.

I am attempting to do this using left joins, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around it.

```
SELECT c.clientId, c.studentFirstName, c.studentLastName, a.date, a.subLocation, SUM(i.invoiceCost-i.invoiceDiscount), d.itemPrice
FROM clients c
JOIN appointments a ON a.clientId = i.clientId
INNER JOIN invoices i ON c.clientId = i.clientId
INNER JOIN invoiceDetail d ON i.invoiceId = d.invoiceId
WHERE c.school = "Test University"
AND a.date > "2019-04-01"
AND a.date < "2019-08-31"
AND i.datePosted > "2019-04-01"
AND i.datePosted < "2019-08-31"
AND (i.invoiceStatus = "Completed" OR i.invoiceStatus = "Invoiced")
AND i.shipping = 0
AND d.itemName LIKE "%tip%"
```

The error I am currently receiving is:

> Unknown column 'c.clientId' in 'on clause'

But, I have a feeling I'm using the wrong approach anyway.

Comment: Eek, first step would be to not mix comma join and standard join syntax. That's just confusing as heck. And you probably want inner joins too.

Comment: @JacobH So sorry! I'm looking up comma vs standard join so I can clean that up.  I apologize, my SQL knowledge is badly out of date

Comment: I think just using the regular join syntax will fix this error. Unless you are actually missing a clientid column in your clients table.

Comment: *Unknown column 'c.clientId' in 'on clause'* Does `clients.clientId` exists really? ensure it is not `clients.Id`, for example...

Comment: Comma in WHERE is an alias of `CROSS JOIN` (and an equivalent of INNER JOIN .. ON 1=1).

Comment: @akina Yeah, it does exist for sure, I just double checked in the database.  I tried to change it to a standard join just now.  I see you have answered down below, so I'm going to go try/learn from your answer

Comment: @JacobH I think I properly changed it from a comma join to a standard join after reading about it.  I'm testing stuff now.  Thanks for letting me know about that change in syntax

Comment: Test does `SELECT * FROM clients c INNER JOIN invoices i ON c.clientId = i.clientId` gives the same error...

Comment: @Akina That shorter query results in no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT c.clientId, c.studentFirstName, c.studentLastName, a.date, a.subLocation, SUM(i.invoiceCost-i.invoiceDiscount), d.itemPrice
FROM clients c
INNER JOIN appointments a ON c.clientId = a.clientId
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON c.clientId = i.clientId
                    AND i.datePosted > "2019-04-01"
                    AND i.datePosted < "2019-08-31"
                    AND i.invoiceStatus IN ("Completed", "Invoiced")
                    AND i.shipping = 0
LEFT JOIN invoiceDetail d ON i.invoiceId = d.invoiceId
                         AND d.itemName LIKE "%tip%"
WHERE c.school = "Test University"
  AND a.date > "2019-04-01"
  AND a.date < "2019-08-31"
```

Comment: This feels like it's really close.  I appreciate you changing this around for me so that I can work with it.  This results in the summing of everybody's invoices under one name, though, instead of breaking it out by customer.  I'll work from this point and I might be able to figure it out!

Comment: @radleybobins *This results in the summing of everybody's invoices under one name* Add GROUP BY by proper expression. I have altered your query for to remove incorrectness only, I have not added anything.

Comment: Excellent, I had thought to add that right before I saw your comment.  I'm letting the query run, but it's taking a while (which is totally fine, I only run it once/year. I just want to wait for the query to finish to see the results)